# Fail to display data to the frontend from api endpoint

Tags: node.js, vue.js

I am learning vuejs as frontend and nodejs as backend, I have created a backend point api which work fine as i can display array of objects of data to a browser also from the postman, I created  frontend service that will take data from backend api, there after I exported and imported to my component where i need to display the data but no error and no data is displayed. I have attached my backend code, frontend service.js that consume backend api  and my vuejs component for viewing data

backend code

```
    const express = require('express');
    const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
    const cors = require('cors')
    const mysql = require('mysql');
    
    
    const app = express()
    const port = process.env.PORT || 4000
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}))
    app.use(bodyParser.json())
    app.use(cors())
    
    //mysql connection
    const pool = mysql.createPool({
     connectionLimit: 10,
     host: 'localhost',
     user: 'root',
     password: '',
     database: 'vuejs'
    });
    
    // get request
    app.get('',(req, res)=>{
      pool.getConnection((err, connection)=>{
    
       if(err) throw err
       console.log(`connected as id ${connection.threadId}`)
    
       connection.query('SELECT * from projects',(err, rows)=>{
         connection.release()//return the connection to pool
         if(!err){
          res.send(rows)
         }else{
          console.log(err)
         }
       })
      })
    })
    
    app.listen(port,()=>console.log(`Application is running at port ${port}`))
```

ProjectService.js code that consume backend api

```
    import axios from 'axios'
    
    const url ='http://localhost:4000/'
    class ProjectService{
     //get project 
     static getProjects(){
      return (resolve, reject)=>{
         try {
           const res = axios.get(url);
           const data = res.data;
           resolve(
            data.map(project=>({
             ...project,
             createdAt: new Date(project.createdAt)
            }))
           )
          
         } catch (error) {
           reject(error)
         }
      }
     }
export default ProjectService
```

Dashboard.vue a component to display my data

```
    <template>
     <div class="dashboard">
       <p class="error" v-if="error">{{error}}</p>
       <h1 class="subheading grey--text">List of Projects</h1>
       <v-container  class="my-5">
         <v-card class="pa-6" v-for="project in projects" :key="project.title">
           <v-layout row :class="`pa-3  project ${project.status}`">
    
             <v-flex xs12 md6>
               <div class="caption grey--text">Project Title</div>
               <div>{{project.title}}</div>
             </v-flex>
    
             <v-flex xs6 sm4 md2>
                <div class="caption grey--text">Person</div>
                <div>{{project.person}}</div>
             </v-flex>
    
              <v-flex xs6 sm4 md2>
                <div class="caption grey--text">Due by</div>
                <div>{{project.due}}</div>
             </v-flex>
    
              <v-flex xs2 sm4 md2>
               <div>
                 <v-chip small :class="` done ${project.status} white--text caption my-2`">{{project.status}}</v-chip>
               </div>
             </v-flex>
           </v-layout>
         
         </v-card>
       </v-container>
        
     </div>
    </template>
    
    <script>
     
    import ProjectService from '../ProjectService'
      export default {
        data() {
          return {
            projects:[],
            error:'',
            title:'',
            person:'',
            due:'',
            status:'',
            
          }
        },
        async created(){
          try {
            this.projects = await ProjectService.getProjects()
            console.log(this.projects)
          } catch (error) {
            this.error = error.message
          }
        }
      }
      
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is the way you made the project.js file. try it like this.

projects.js

```
import axios from "axios";

const url = "http://localhost:4000/";

export default async () => {
  return await axios
    .get(url)
    .then((response) => {
      const data = response.data;

      data.map((project) => ({
        ...project,
        createdAt: new Date(project.createdAt),
      }));

      return data;
    })
    .catch((e) => {
      return e;
    });
};
```

on your dashboard.vue file

```
<template>
  <div class="dashboard">
    <p class="error" v-if="error">{{ error }}</p>
    <h1 class="subheading grey--text">List of Projects</h1>
    <v-container class="my-5">
      <v-card class="pa-6" v-for="project in projects" :key="project.title">
        <v-layout row :class="`pa-3  project ${project.status}`">
          <v-flex xs12 md6>
            <div class="caption grey--text">Project Title</div>
            <div>{{ project.title }}</div>
          </v-flex>

          <v-flex xs6 sm4 md2>
            <div class="caption grey--text">Person</div>
            <div>{{ project.person }}</div>
          </v-flex>

          <v-flex xs6 sm4 md2>
            <div class="caption grey--text">Due by</div>
            <div>{{ project.due }}</div>
          </v-flex>

          <v-flex xs2 sm4 md2>
            <div>
              <v-chip
                small
                :class="` done ${project.status} white--text caption my-2`"
                >{{ project.status }}</v-chip
              >
            </div>
          </v-flex>
        </v-layout>
      </v-card>
    </v-container>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import ProjectService from "./projects";

export default {
  layout: "center-eight",
  data() {
    return {
      projects: [],
      error: "",
      title: "",
      person: "",
      due: "",
      status: "",
    };
  },
  created() {
    this.getList();
  },
  methods: {
    async getList() {
      try {
        this.projects = await ProjectService();
        console.log(this.projects);
      } catch (error) {
        this.error = error.message;
      }
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

test it and tell me your status. if it is not working we will find another solution.

Comment: I get an error message that context is defined but never used  also from a browser console i get undefined error message

Comment: I have updates my answer. now it it tested with my local api. If your backend works fine as you describe, it should work with the new answer.

Comment: It has worked out now i can display the data to my front end

Answer (score 0):

You're not calling the created function that's why it's not working here!

Script tag:

```sh
<script>
 
import ProjectService from '../ProjectService'
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        projects:[],
        error:'',
        title:'',
        person:'',
        due:'',
        status:'',
        
      }
    },
    methods: {
     async created(){
      try {
        this.projects = await ProjectService.getProjects()
        console.log(this.projects)
      } catch (error) {
        this.error = error.message
      }
    }
},
   mounted() {
    this.created();
}
  }
  
</script>
```

Comment: I made changes as you suggested but still no data displaying also no error